# Morris.js stacked bar chart order/revese by Y key

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I have Morris.js stacked bar chart:

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 150, b: 60 },
    { y: '2007', a: 175,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 150,  b: 40 },
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
  stacked: true
});
```

http://jsbin.com/bazomocoba/edit?html,js,output

What I'm trying to achieve is to draw the first Y key at the top, then the second one below and etc. In the example this is the 'a' key, which need to be on top of all. Basically to revert the way it draws all little bars in a bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reverting the data passed to `Morris.Bar`?

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [ // reverse b and a
    { y: '2006', b: 60, a: 150 },
    { y: '2007', b: 65, a: 175 },
    { y: '2008', b: 40, a: 150 },
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['b', 'a'], // reverse b and a
  labels: ['Series B', 'Series A'], // reverse labels
  stacked: true
});
```

Comment: I came to the same solution after few more hours tinkering it. I'll accept the answer as correct anyway, since this is the way I've solved my problem.